# Positioned OverlayEntry inconsistency between debug and release moe

Tags: flutter

I'm implementing some tutorial steps in my app using Overlay, but the position of the inserted entries are different in debug and release mode. Also, it looks even worse in production on iOS:

Debug mode:

[image]

Release mode (Android):

[image]

Release mode (iOS):

[image]

And here is the code:

```
  Future<void> _handleTutorial() async {
    if (!widget.enableTutorial)
      return;

    // Get sizes
    final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    // Render if tutorial is enabled
    _tutorialEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        top: offset.dy,
        left: offset.dx,
        right: 0,
        child: FadeInOutAnimation(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              
              // Overlay widget
              Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: DatesTitle(section: widget.section, isTutorialSample: true),
              ),
              
              // Information text
              PopUpAnimation(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 18),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: const [
                              TutorialInclinedTapHand(),
                              SizedBox(width: 20),
                              Expanded(child: TutorialText('Tap to change the number of days in this province'))
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          TutorialButton(onPressed: widget.onTutorialComplete)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
    _overlay.insert(_tutorialEntry);

  }
```

How do I fix these inconsistences?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the debug banner. You can set it false and position the widgets again.

```
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I see no difference after disabling the debug banner :/

Comment: Actually, there is a difference: on release mode (Android) with the banner disabled, the date card gets even more down the screen.

Comment: There is an unnecessary Column in your code, `PopUpAnimation`. After removing it, you can change the other Column with `Stack` and `Positioned`.

Comment: I "fixed" the issue by adding a delay between the widget creation and the overlay insertions. No idea why this worked.